# Does JQuery Mobile interfere with Javascript or is it an issue with formatting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I know the code works because it was tested in JSfiddle, but it's something about putting it into this HTML that then causes an error, unless JQuery Mobile it interfering?

So I have stripped away the CSS in order to test, but no matter what I take away it just causes error when adding a new item to the list.

Here is the working version:
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VHe6C/)

```
<title>Checklist</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js">
    </script>

<script>
$('#add').on('click', function (e) {
var $this = $(this);
var $firstRow=$this.closest('table').find('tr:first');
var $newRow = $firstRow.clone();

var input = $newRow.find(':input').remove();
input.prop('checked', false);
$newRow.empty().append(input).append('&nbsp;'+$('#textinput4').val());

$newRow.insertAfter($firstRow);
});​
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="check">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Checklist
            </h3>
            <a data-role="button" data-transition="fade" href="#about" class="ui-btn-left">
                Back
            </a>

        </div>
        <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
            <div data-role="collapsible-set">

            <form name="emailform" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="form-to-email.php" method="get">
              <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                 <label for='name'>Festival name: </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="name">

                    <h3>
                        Before you go
                    </h3>

                        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical">
                            <legend>
                            </legend>
                            <input name="checkbox62" id="checkbox62" type="checkbox" />
                            <label for="checkbox62">
                                Charge all batteries. Phones, cameras etc
                            </label>
                            <input name="checkbox63" id="checkbox63" type="checkbox" />
                            <label for="checkbox63">
                                Save your friends numbers
                            </label>
                            <input name="checkbox64" id="checkbox64" type="checkbox" />
                            <label for="checkbox64">
                                Check out festival site rules!
                            </label>
                            <tr><td><input name="checkbox65" id="checkbox65" type="checkbox" /></td>
                            <td><label for="checkbox65">Get directions for where you are going</label></td></tr>
                        </fieldset>

                     <h3>My items</h3>
                    <table id="myTable">
<tr>
    <td>
    <label for="checkbox65">
        <input name="checkbox65" class="checkbox65" type="checkbox" />
        Get directions for where you are going
    </label>
    </td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <label for="textinput4">
                Add new item
                <input name="new_item" id="textinput4" placeholder="" value="" type="text" />
            </label>
        </fieldset>
        <button id="add">Add</button>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>​


  </form>
```

Comment: Your scripts may not work without the correct `type` attribute. Try changing your `<script>` tags to include `type`. Example: `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: The `type` attribute in HTML5 is no longer required. http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_script_type.asp

Comment: @andleer I did not realize that. But still, shouldn't `type` be included for backwards compatibility?

Comment: jQuery Mobile... Almost certain that it is running in a HTML5 environment.

Comment: This markup is poorly formed. I can't make heads or tails of it. `<tr>` within `<fieldset>`. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a case of your event handler being bound to early. When you are trying to bind your click event to the add button the add button hasn't been loaded into the DOM yet. One thing which  you can do is simply move your script to the end of your body.

A better solution would be to use event delegation, for example

```
    $(document).on('click', '#add', function(e) {
          var $this = $(this);
          var $firstRow = $this.closest('table').find('tr:first');
          var $newRow = $firstRow.clone();

          var input = $newRow.find(':input').remove();
          input.prop('checked', false);
          $newRow.empty().append(input).append('&nbsp;' + $('#textinput4').val());

          $newRow.insertAfter($firstRow);
      });
```

(You might still want to move your script to the end of your page for performance reasons so that it doesn't block the loading of your page).